# Swift Trigger click in textfield

Tags: swift, button, triggers, click, textfield

In my app I'm using some pickerviews that appear when I click on a textfield, that works fine!

I wanted to do the same when I click on a Left Bar Button Item. I can't do it with the button because buttons doesn't have `inputView` property, needed for associate the pickerview to the button (in this case). So I want to have a hidden textfield that is programmatically clicked when I click on the button (when it's clicked it show the pickerview and change the button name, that's all done)

Is that possible?
The best I can do right know is something like this

```
 txtFantasma.perform(
        #selector(becomeFirstResponder),
        with: nil,
        afterDelay: 0.1
    )
```

It works fine, but just work at the first time.

EDIT1:

I've tried to make it with buttons... The popover is showing, now I wanted to click in one button and dismiss the popover and pass data to the main viewcontroller.

```
class ViewPopup:UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        }

    @IBAction func btTituloAsc(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainview") as! ViewController
        next.ordenacao = "TituloAsc"

        self.present(next, animated: true,completion:nil)

    }

}
```

This works, but the main controller is showed without the Navigation Bar! How can I do the same but show de Navigation Bar?

Comment: To me it sounds like you are trying to apply certain Microsoft technologies (triggers) to Apple ones (MVC). Using MVC - which BTW isn't *just* an Apple thing but a form of programming - could you show code as to *how* your picker view appears when you tap/click on a textfield? This will help us to help you out. You *probably shouldn't need* to have a hidden textfield in order to bring up a picker, but maybe... not? Thanks.

Comment: The code I've got is like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81MEUcx-mDA . The problem is that I want to do the same but instead of having the textfield I wanna do it when I click on a Left Bar Button Item. That button will be used to user choose what kind of sort he want for the tableview data

Comment: Sorry, but I don't wish to watch a five minute YouTube video. Could you be a bit more specific with your issue? Is the picker that works in a keyboard that you get to through this textfield? If so, then *no* you can't bring up a keyboard - custom or other - via a bar button. However, you *can bring up a subview that "looks" like a keyboard.

Comment: the code is all showed in the final of the video... but anyway, when I use the textfield to show the pickerview I need to do this step `txtFantasma.inputView = PickerOrdenacao`. With a button I can't do that! That's the problem... so I wanna simulate the click in the textfield when I click in the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplistic way to do it, is just display the pickerView as a popover once the user taps the button and then change the buttons title accordingly.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking on that.. I'll try to do it

Comment: Let me know if u need assisstance

Comment: please check my Edit

Comment: @luidgi27 you need to create a modal segue, for example a popover or something similar

Comment: so if i've got 10 buttons i need 10 modal segue?

Comment: Do you have 10 pickers?? If you have 1 picked you can connect all buttons to the same IBAction and utilize the sender. Just change the title of the sender

Comment: like I said I decide try with buttons and not with picker... I'm kind of tired, if I can't end this today I'll try again tomorrow and then i say something. thanks for the tips

Comment: If you send me a link to your app on GitHub il be able to help you out

Comment: I made the pickerview and can dismiss it and get the value selected. I sort the array but my tableview don't update the data! It is possible to send you the code and you can check it? I can't understand what's wrong

Comment: I already solved it! Don't know if I made it in the best way possible but it's done. thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glade I could help